# Asp.net mvc 4 simple membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got some silly questions, but I'm quite new in mvc and haven't found any appropriate answers,so:

1: In asp .net mvc4 internet application, as you create a new project VS. creates registration by default. If u register a new account, does mvc store this in a database? (I read that it stores, and can be found in appdata, but it's empty for me, and in server explorer there is no connetion, but I can log in and out after registration, it works perfectly.) Do I have to set a new sql server for VS or it handles this by itself? So how does this exactly work?

2: My goal is to modify the registration form to store id,name, fullname, email, registration date as you register. How can i achieve this by "extending" the default registration?

Answer (score 0):

It does use a db. Check the connection string in web.config. VS 2010 uses SQL Express I believe and VS2012 uses localdb. SQL is installed with VS. The db file is usually installed in the app data folder but it does get generated until the first user is created. I suggest you get Microsoft SQL Management Studio if you want to look inside the DB, or use sever explorer from within VS.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2012/11/15/customize-the-simplemembership-in-asp-net-mvc-4-0.aspx) perfectly answers to both of your questions